# I want my if loop to do nothing if certain conditions are met

Tags: c#, winforms

i want my if loop to do nothing when the conditions that i gave it are there 
i'm new to C# and winform so i searched the internet but didnt find an answer that seems to work and right now i have no idea what to do.

,Mo

[screenshot of the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2JRn.png)

Comment: If the `if` does nothing, why have it in the first place?

Comment: It´s quite unlike what you are asking. Do you want something that should be done when your condition is not met? Then use `else` after your `if`. Furthermore there is no such thing as an if-loop. You probably mean a loop which contains an if-statement?

Comment: Your code doesn't contain a loop but only an `if`-statement (a `double` which is a value type is never `null`).

Comment: I can´t see *any loop*, in the code provided you, probably, want `return`;

Comment: what im doing is calc for school and i want the if loop to do nothing if there s no second number because if smbdy enters enter while there is only one number the programm closes and shows an error

Comment: and im really sorry if i dont know the names of the diffrent things after all im still pretty new to all of this

Comment: put all the code you want to execute in else and in if just keep the error message buddy. and the if loop will just check condition give the error and do nothing

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of linking a screenshot.

Comment: Please insert your code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to "cancel" all operations in the current method, right? You can use `return;` to do that:

```
if(value2 == null) return;
```

There is just one other thing wrong with your code: `value2` will never be `null`.

```
decimal value2;
if(!decimal.TryParse(result[1], out value2)) return;
```

should work a lot better ;)

Comment: He's not in a loop though, think he's mixed terminology.

Comment: It's worth noting that this will never be true because `value2` is a double.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see *any loop* in the code provided. You want to change `Parse` to `TryParse` and use `return` in order to return from the method (== *do nothing*):

```
public void button14_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string[] result = input1.Text.Split(Oprator);
  //TODO: it may appear, that you want TryParse here as well
  decimal value1 = decimal.Parse(result[0]);
  decimal value2;

  // If you have too few items, and thus you have no "value2" - do nothing
  if (result.Length < 2)
    return; 

  // Try parse result[1] to decimal; if parse fails (e.g. result[1] == "zzz") - do nothing
  if (!decimal.TryParse(result[1], out value2)) 
    return;

  // you have value1, value2, Oprator; put required logic here  
  switch (Oprator) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about a "While" loop?

```
    int n = 1;
    while (n < 6) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Current value of n is {0}", n);
        n++;
    }
```

Comment: I would use a for loop there, when you need to do something n times y find way more clear `for(int i=0;i<6;i++){ }`